# How to fetch data from a Collection document onUpdate?

Tags: typescript, firebase, google-cloud-firestore, google-cloud-functions

I am trying to query data from a collection "users" in firebase onUpdate a document "bulkMsgs" but every time I do that I get "Error getting user".

both methods are working separately fine but when I combine them the error is happening.

What I am missing here?!

```
var functions = require("firebase-functions");
let admin = require('firebase-admin');
admin.initializeApp(functions.config().firebase);

    exports.bulkMsg = functions.firestore
        .document('/bulkMsgs/{bulkMsgsId}').onUpdate((snap, context) => {

            const newValue = snap.after.data();
            const regDate = newValue.regDate;

            admin.firestore().collection('users').get().then(onUser => {
                onUser.forEach(oneUser => {
                    if (oneUser.data().notification === "true") {
                       console.log(oneUser.id);
                    }
                });
                return true;

            }).catch(err => {
                console.log('Error getting user', err);
            });


            return true;
        });
```

[Image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/y79W8.png) of the error in the CF log.

Comment: And what is the value of `err` in the `console.log('Error getting user', err);`? In other words what is the exact error you get? In any case note that you need to return the promise returned by the `get()` method.

Comment: I have updated the original post and added the error message.

Comment: Ok thanks. And in your code, is there anything in the following if? if (oneUser.data().notification === "true") {

Comment: Also, how many documents do you have in the `users` collection?

Comment: Yes just printing the user id
console.log(oneUser.id);

Comment: No. of documents around 1500

Comment: And are they other parts of your code that you didn't share in your question? When debugging a Cloud Function it is very important to see the entire code, not only some snippets.

Comment: Just the lib declarations 

var functions = require("firebase-functions");
let admin = require('firebase-admin');
admin.initializeApp(functions.config().firebase);

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/201013/discussion-between-ahmed-abosrie-and-renaud-tarnec).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are getting an `Error: 4 DEADLINE_EXCEEDED`. Doing a quick [search](https://www.google.com/search?client=firefox-b-d&ei=A0SoXfnDGsSdkgXL1KjgBA&q=firebase%20cloud%20functions%20error%204%20deadline%20exceeded&oq=firebase%20cloud%20functions%20error%204%20deadline%20exceeded&gs_l=psy-ab.3...3267.3393..3640...0.0..0.97.176.2......0....1..gws-wiz.......33i160.dYRum5DR9JE&ved=0ahUKEwi50bW-jKPlAhXEjqQKHUsqCkwQ4dUDCAo&uact=5) on the net shows that it seems to occur when "the requests that you're making take too long."

However, with regards to the clarifications you gave in the comments above, it doesn't seem that you are dealing with high volumes.

What happens if you return the promise returned by the `get()` asynchronous method, as follows.

```
exports.bulkMsg = functions.firestore
    .document('/bulkMsgs/{bulkMsgsId}').onUpdate((snap, context) => {

        const newValue = snap.after.data();
        const regDate = newValue.regDate;

        return admin.firestore().collection('users').get()
        .then(onUser => {
            onUser.forEach(oneUser => {
                if (oneUser.data().notification === "true") {
                   console.log(oneUser.id);
                }
            });
            return null;
        }).catch(err => {
            console.log('Error getting user', err);
            return null;
        });

    });
```

As a matter of fact, you MUST return a Promise or a value in a background triggered Cloud Function. I would suggest you watch the 3 videos about "JavaScript Promises" from the Firebase video series: https://firebase.google.com/docs/functions/video-series/ which explain this key point.